# WAP in javascript to insert new line in each and every whitespace occurence

Tags: javascript, regex

// My code in javascript

```
const data=['City State Country'];
const output=data[0].split(' ').join('\n');
console.log(output)
```

My Output is

```
City\nState\nCountry
```

My Desired output is

```
City
State
Country
```

Comment: When I run this code, it prints it out with new lines rather than "\n"s. I think the environment you are printing it out to just doesn't support line breaks in printed strings.

Comment: I am executing this code in VS code.

Comment: It does not matter where you execute it, you have no issue, the output is as expected. You have newlines in the output text, you just see the console output, which is a *string literal*.

Answer (score -2):

You can try joining by "\r\n"

\r\n is a Windows Style

\n is a POSIX Style

```js
const data=['City State Country'];
const output=data[0].split(' ').join('\r\n');
console.log(output)
```

Comment: const data=['City State Country'];
const output=data[0].split(' ').join('\r\n');
console.log(output)
City
State
Country

output
'City\r\nState\r\nCountry'

//When I tried to execute this code in chrome console, I received the correct result but when I just type output, I received 'City\r\nState\r\nCountry'.